# Permanently add directory to PATH environment variable in Java

Tags: java, path

I am trying to permanently add a directory to the PATH environment variable in Java, as part of an installer. Is there any way to do that?

I have seen answers that use something like this:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("setx /M path "%path%;C:\your\path\here\" ");`
However often there are comments that don't recommed doing this.

Comment: Hey, it isn't generally recommended because setx is platform specific to Windows.

Comment: Personally I would avoid messing with people's PATH. Better to make a launcher ('shortcut' in Windows)